# vee-validate how to set digit limit between two number?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vee-validate

I am trying to restrict the number of digits a user can input between 3-6.

For some reason, I can't find how to do that.

this is the code I have to force user to add three digits only

```
<input type="text"  name='account-field-3' v-validate="'required|digits:3'" placeholder="6" class="form-control" >
```

But what I need is between 3-6.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `min` and `max`

Max: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#max

Min: https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/rules.html#min

```
<input type="text"  name='account-field-3' v-validate="'required|min:3|max:6'" placeholder="6" class="form-control" >
```

Comment: This to validate mix max length not integral value

Answer (score 8):

Its been long but here is a solution which worked for me.

```js
//Javascript File
import { min, max, numeric } from "vee-validate/dist/rules";
import { extend, validate, localize } from "vee-validate";
import en from "vee-validate/dist/locale/en.json";
localize({
    en
});

extend("min", min);
extend("max", max);
extend("numeric", numeric);

extend('digits_between', {
  async validate(value, { min, max }) {
        const res = await validate(value, `numeric|min:${min}|max:${max}`,)
            return res.valid;
  },
  params: ['min', 'max'],
  message: 'The {_field_} must be between {min} and {max} digits'
});
```

```html
<!-- vue file -->
<ValidationProvider
  rules="digits_between:3,8"
  v-slot="{ errors }"
  name="Country"
>
  <input v-model="value" type="text">
  <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
</ValidationProvider>
```